# Why does this return None; dec2asc?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm currently trying to convert decimal to ASCII characters, the typeable ones. I know there is an inbuilt function but I was given a task to do it manually

```
def dec2asc(int_value):
    integer_val = int(int_value)
    if integer_val % 2 == 0 or (integer_val + 1) % 2 == 0:  # checking if dec_value is a decimal or not
        if 32 <= integer_val >= 128:
            return str(ascii_chars[integer_val])
    else:
        return 'Invalid integer value'


print dec2asc('43')
```

I should be receiving `+` but instead I get `None`

Comment: What do you expect to happen if the first `if` passes and the second doesn't?

Comment: Also, that `>=` is pointing the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have incorrect check of integer_val. You sre not checking between. Turn the right around to

```
    if 32 <= integer_val <= 128:
        return str(ascii_chars[integer_val])
```